# Android InApp Purchase Null pointer exception

Tags: android, in-app-billing

I had implemented inApp purchase in my application but sometimes it gives me NPE, below is stack trace. I can post the code also if anyone interested.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service com.market.BillingService@48400380 with null: java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:3063)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$3600(ActivityThread.java:125)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2096)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:871)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:629)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.market.BillingService.handleCommand(BillingService.java:369)
at com.market.BillingService.onStart(BillingService.java:359)
at android.app.Service.onStartCommand(Service.java:420)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:3053)
... 10 more
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.market.BillingService.handleCommand(BillingService.java:369)
at com.market.BillingService.onStart(BillingService.java:359)
at android.app.Service.onStartCommand(Service.java:420)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:3053)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$3600(ActivityThread.java:125)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2096)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:871)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:629)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here goes relevant code

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    ResponseHandler.register(mDungeonsPurchaseObserver);
}
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    ResponseHandler.unregister(mDungeonsPurchaseObserver);
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    mBillingService.unbind();
}
```

And in OnCreate()

```
mDungeonsPurchaseObserver = new WMBPurchaseObserver(mHandler);

mBillingService = new BillingService();
mBillingService.setContext(BuyModel.this);
ResponseHandler.register(mDungeonsPurchaseObserver);
```

onClick of buy Button

```
if (!mBillingService.checkBillingSupported())
{
    showDialog(DIALOG_CANNOT_CONNECT_ID);
}
mBillingService.requestPurchase("android.test.purchased", null);
```

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6759802/android-inapp-purchase-null-pointer-exception

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In your BillingService.java onStart method guard for null intent like this

```
 if (null != intent) {
        handleCommand(intent, startId);
 }
```

I believe this is caused by null intent. Try out!

Comment: I have implemented your method lets see if that since my app doesnt crash everytimes it happens 1 out of 10 times or more rare

Comment: I believe there is one more place you need to guard for null intent. Can you post logcat for crash?

Comment: I don't remember right now, but I am sure I had this sort of crashes as well with the example code and fixed it by guarding for null. Crash log would help me recall it.

Comment: I have posted the crashlog for reference, have look if that might help you recalling I am fed up of this issue

Comment: With my solution does it still crash?

Comment: Thanks I haven't got crashed since I implemented your method I am going to test it for more and I will be accepting your answer +1

Comment: The reason this check needs to be in place is that the service can be restarted by the system if it is killed before processing is complete and the intent is null because you are supposed to resume processing your last command.

Comment: This solution is only a workaround to prevent your app from crashing. @Jerry's explanation seems right to me which means you need to take care of stopping all instances of the services. I am currently battling the same problem in the same situation (in-app billing). I too took the code from the sample on Android's developer blog.

Answer (score 7):

I found the correct way to fix this. Well actually depends on how you look at it. If you don't want your service to be restarted after its process is killed then you need to override onStartCommand and return START_NOT_STICKY. Like this:

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
   handleCommand(intent, startId);
   return START_NOT_STICKY;
}
```

See [START_NOT_STICKY](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#START_NOT_STICKY). If you **do** want the service to be restarted every time it is killed then the current chosen answer is the one for you since Android will restart your service after it is killed with a null intent. Again, see the link I provided.

**Oh and [onStart](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#onStart%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29) is deprecated.**

Comment: So what would be the correct way for a billing service? Restart or no restart?

Comment: No restart would be correct since BillingService needn't run in the background if the activity using it is no longer in the foreground. You must however think about restarting the service (or bind to it) again once your activity restarts.

Comment: Couldn't the server response be a little late, and actually arrive when app is not in foreground? Surely you will want billing information to arrive even if app is not in foreground?

Comment: Just don't unbind() from the service in your activity's onPause(), Keep a reference to the service active then Android won't GC the process. However, remember to unbind and remove all references in your activity's onDestroy because your app may be killed by the OS if it decides to and in that case you must clean-up references for proper GC.